# .NET 4.0 on Windows Azure?

Tags: .net-4.0, azure

My google-fu is failing me on this one.

As a possible solution to [Unit Testing .NET 3.5 projects using MStest in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679404/unit-testing-net-3-5-projects-using-mstest-in-vs2010) (but I've put this in a seperate question because it's kind of unrelated):

Is there any information available regarding if/when .NET 4.0 support will be added to Windows Azure?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for .Net 4.0 was released with the June 2010 Azure SDK. The current SDK can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/cc974146).

Answer (score 2):

The indirect answer to your question to be found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/450add2a-ea93-4d79-b171-44072fa3c8d4/

In short, .NET 4 support in Windows Azure has not been announced.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The Azure team announces that .NET 4 will be supported within 90 days of the .NET 4 RTM release date which was April 10. 2010.

http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsazure/archive/2010/04/07/upcoming-support-in-windows-azure-for-net-framework-4.aspx